# The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `dict` instance.\nOriginal exception text was: 'ilan_no'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

Whenever I use `values()` method in queryset I get the error on title. If I use a simpler query in views.py, like `Ilan.objects.all()` It works fine. So, It seems that the error is due to the value() method. How can I fix it? BTW, ilan_no is a identifier number for each row. I have used ModelSerializers but nothing has changed.

Django==2.1
djangorestframework==3.11.0

**models.py:**

```
class Ilan(models.Model):
    ilan_no = models.IntegerField(unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    url = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    add_date= models.DateField()
    origin = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    district = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class IlanSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    ilan_no = serializers.IntegerField()
    url = serializers.CharField()
    ilan_tarihi = serializers.DateField()
    origin = serializers.CharField()
    city = serializers.CharField()
    district = serializers.CharField()
    price = serializers.IntegerField()
```

**views.py**

```
class IlcePriceAndSizeDistributionListView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Ilan.objects.annotate(year=ExtractYear('ilan_tarihi')).annotate(month=ExtractMonth('ilan_tarihi')).values(
        'district', 'year', 'month').annotate(average_m2=Avg('m2_net')).annotate(average=Avg('price')).annotate(count=Count('ilan_no')).order_by('year', 'month')
    serializer_class = IlanSerializer
```

**Whole error:**

```
Got KeyError when attempting to get a value for field `ilan_no` on serializer `IlanSerializer`.\nThe serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `dict` instance.\nOriginal exception text was: 'ilan_no'.
```

**Whole trace_back:**

```
    Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/charts/api/v1/ilce_price_size

Django Version: 2.1
Python Version: 3.7.4
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'charts.apps.ChartsConfig',
 'predictions.apps.PredictionsConfig']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\wsl\emlakanalizDjangoApp\.env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py" in get_attribute
  454.             return get_attribute(instance, self.source_attrs)

File "C:\wsl\emlakanalizDjangoApp\.env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py" in get_attribute
  92.                 instance = instance[attr]

During handling of the above exception ('ilan_no'), another exception occurred:

File "C:\wsl\emlakanalizDjangoApp\.env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\wsl\emlakanalizDjangoApp\.env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\wsl\emlakanalizDjangoApp\.env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\wsl\emlakanalizDjangoApp\.env\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  54.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\wsl\emlakanalizDjangoApp\.env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\wsl\emlakanalizDjangoApp\.env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in dispatch
  505.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "C:\wsl\emlakanalizDjangoApp\.env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in handle_exception
  465.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "C:\wsl\emlakanalizDjangoApp\.env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in raise_uncaught_exception
  476.         raise exc

File "C:\wsl\emlakanalizDjangoApp\.env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in dispatch
  502.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\wsl\emlakanalizDjangoApp\.env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\generics.py" in get
  199.         return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\wsl\emlakanalizDjangoApp\.env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py" in list
  43.             return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

File "C:\wsl\emlakanalizDjangoApp\.env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in data
  760.         ret = super().data

File "C:\wsl\emlakanalizDjangoApp\.env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in data
  260.                 self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)

File "C:\wsl\emlakanalizDjangoApp\.env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in to_representation
  678.             self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable

File "C:\wsl\emlakanalizDjangoApp\.env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in <listcomp>
  678.             self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable

File "C:\wsl\emlakanalizDjangoApp\.env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in to_representation
  516.                 attribute = field.get_attribute(instance)

File "C:\wsl\emlakanalizDjangoApp\.env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py" in get_attribute
  487.             raise type(exc)(msg)

Exception Type: KeyError at /charts/api/v1/ilce_price_size
Exception Value: "Got KeyError when attempting to get a value for field `ilan_no` on serializer `IlanSerializer`.\nThe serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `dict` instance.\nOriginal exception text was: 'ilan_no'."
```

Comment: It seems that the queryset is returning a field which is not defined in the serializer, try to use Model serializer  and define the fields =  `'__ all __ '|.   When you are running the same query on shell what is the name of the returned field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missed `ilan_no` field in `values`. Just add it in fields in values method:

```
  queryset = Ilan.objects.annotate(year=ExtractYear('ilan_tarihi')).annotate(month=ExtractMonth('ilan_tarihi')).values(
    'district', 'year', 'month', 'ilan_no').annotate(average_m2=Avg('m2_net')).annotate(average=Avg('price')).annotate(count=Count('ilan_no')).order_by('year', 'month')
```

Comment: Thank you. I got it. It makes me add all fields in serializers.py I don't serialize fields that I don't use in views.